# EF 4.1 Code First Multiple Result Sets

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to execute a Raw SQL query that returns multiple result sets. Is that possible in EF CF ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

Yes you can! ;) You can perform a raw sql query using DbCommand in Entity Framework Code First too.

You can perform queries with multiple result sets and jump to the next result set using `NextResult()` method of the `SqlDataReader` class.

#### Sample

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {

    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

            DbCommand db = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            db.CommandText = "SELECT propertie1 FROM Table1; SELECT propertie1 from Table2";
            try
            {
                DbDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // read your data from result set 1
                    string value = Convert.ToString(reader["propertie1"]);
                }

                reader.NextResult();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // read your data from result set 2
                    string value = Convert.ToString(reader["propertie1"]);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Exception handling
            }
            finally
            {
                if (db.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    db.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 10: Raw SQL Queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/04/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-10-raw-sql-queries.aspx)

Comment: Does this handle multiple result sets?

Comment: Yes, you can jump to the next result set using NextResult() method of the SqlDataReader class.

Comment: How ?? I don't see any SqlDataReader ?

Comment: I changed my answer. Now there is a little sample.

Comment: How do I read data?

How do I materialize Reader into objects ? is there a translate method ?

Comment: Oh. But this is the tedious old way. I could have done that using separate connection.  What is CF for then? I thought there is a context.Translate<Type> method

Thanks anyway!!